# Controlling Intersection of CSS 3D Transformed Elements

Tags: css, 3d, transform

Have been experimenting with CSS 3D transforms and am confused why I'm not getting the expected results in browsers other than Safari.

Basically I have 2 sibling elements that are on top of one another (on the same z-index). If I put a `transform: rotateX(xdeg)` on one and leave the other untouched I would expect to see one half of the transformed element hidden behind the untouched element and the other side to be sticking out.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="outer"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px;
    -webkit-perspective: 30em;
    perspective: 30em;
}
.outer{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg);
    transform: rotateX(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border:5px black solid;
}
.inner{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    background: orange;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    transform: rotate
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jaredkhan/4VRTb/3/
The fiddle uses the same code.

The bottom of the transformed element is not displayed in front of the element that is untouched despite theoretically being closer in 3D space. This does however, work as I would expect in Safari. Am I missing something? I've tried explicitly putting them both on the same z-index and even nesting the inner one, nothing seems to be working. It's likely I'm just being dumb but please help.

Thanks

Comment: [Do you mean like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/4VRTb/2/)

Comment: Nah, I'm talking more about the intersection of the two elements (have changed the title to reflect this). They should intersect like they do in Safari where the back of the black ring is hidden behind the orange element but the front is visible because it is in front of it.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. You want the black lines to go through the orange ones. I'm afraid that is not possible to have elements go through other elements like that in CSS at the moment (perhaps with WebGL it is? I'm not sure). What I would recommend is making the equivalent of what you want to show by cutting off the top of the black lines and then place it in front of the orange square then rotate it. It will give the illusion of the same thing

Comment: Yeah, I did resort to that in the end. I was really hoping it was possible without that though, it works perfectly in Safari! I'm certain it's possible in WebGL. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Children are rendered one by one onto the plane of the parent element. You need to set `transform-style: preserve-3d` on the parent to prevent this ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8tu1g0wo/)):

```
.container{
    ...
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

More info on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style

(I'm not sure whether this even existed back in 2014 when you asked the question, but it works now in 2019.)